# Conditional Probability (Baye's Rule) question with urns

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

> There are two urns  A  and  B. Urn  A  contains 1 red ball and  2  white balls, whereas urn  B  contains  2  red balls and  1  white ball. Calculate the conditional probability that a randomly chosen ball belonged to urn  A  given that it is white.

I know, that the answer is 0.6666...
But I can't figure the way how to apply the Baye's rule to the conditions.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Do you have any thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Are we to take that Urn A and Urn B may be chosen with equal probability, and one random ball extracted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let A be the event that urn A chosen, B be the event that Urn B chosen,
and W be the event that a white ball is chosen.

Using Bayes' Rule and the law of total probability,

P(From Urn A | it is white) $= \dfrac{P(A)\cdot P(W|A)}{P(A)\cdot P(W|A) + P(B)\cdot(P(W|B)} =\dfrac{\dfrac12
\cdot\dfrac23}{\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac23+\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac13}=\dfrac23$

Answer (score 2):

$$ P(A|W) = \frac{P(A \cap W)}{P(W)}  $$
Assuming either urn is equally probable ..

$P(W) = \frac 12$  ( 3 out of 6 balls are white )

$P(A \cap W)=\frac12 \times \frac 23 $